# python Illegal instruction on AIX5.2

Tags: python, aix

I run my python script functions like this:
read from a text file, and store the data as dict. But when in the loop, an Illegal instruction occurs. why this happens?
the code is like this:

```
d={}
datafile=open('a.txt') # a big text file
for line in datafile:
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    for token in line.split():
        print("Parsing line %d." % token[0])
        d[(int(token[0]))]=token[1:]
```

then the message is like this:

```
Parsing line 1.
Parsing line 2.
............
Parsing line 1064
Parsing line 1065
Illegal instruction
```

what's the problem? my platform is python 2.6.2 on AIX 5.2.
please help me, thanks!

Comment: What is printing "Illegal instruction"? What else is printed?

Answer (score 3):

This looks very wrong. `token` is a string in an array of strings returned by `line.split()`. So `token[0]` is the first character of that string. Therefore I don't believe that you'll ever get anything like `Parsing line 1065` in your output. As Mark wrote, you'd see a `TypeError`.

Please post

1. the real code
2. the real data (an excerpt of the first few lines and line 1065/1066 would suffice)
3. the real error message.

Otherwise there's no way to help you.

Comment: +1  Formatting a string with "%d" should give a TypeError;  it seems very unlikely that this code is producing the results described.

Comment: The second `for` loop appears to be completely unnecessary for what he's appearing to be trying to do.